# RESTful web APIs using MVVM architecture

Tags: architecture, rest, api, web-api, mvvm

As the title implies, I would like to know if it is possible to create RESTful web APIs using MVVM architecture?
Or we can use just MVC pattern to create web APIs?

Comment: for an Api the View is static. so you dont have any interactions to deal with. MVVM doesnt make much sense

Comment: @Ewan Do you mean it is not possible?

Comment: probably, it depends on your interpretation.

Comment: @Ewan 
Can MVVM return JSON as a response? Can we have different types of views for a ModelView in MVVM?

Comment: i think you need to add some extra meat to this question. What do you think an MVVM api would look like? which parts are which What dont you understand etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVVM (and MVC for that matter) are user interface design patterns. The main goal of these two patterns is separation of concerns between business logic and user interaction logic. Since a Web API has no user interface, user interface design patterns do not apply.

MVVM solves different problems than what a Web API encounters. Typically the clients of a Web API – the consumers of that service – will utilize MVC or MVVM, because those applications have a user interface.

When choosing an application framework for a Web API, security, scalability, performance, ease of deployment, and ease of reuse are the driving concerns.  Managing user interactions is not a concern for a Web API. You don't need a design pattern to implement web services. Many newer frameworks have been created that focus on the unique needs of Web services and micro services. These frameworks tend to reduce complexity and software layers in favor of letting your code get closer to the HTTP protocol, which is desirable when implementing REST services.

Comment: Are they UI design pattern or software design pattern?

Comment: @Commander: UI design patterns are just a specialization of software design patterns. The term "software design pattern" is more general, and could apply to any area of an application. User interface design patterns are focused on common problems only encountered in applications that have a user interface.

Comment: And specifically, UI design patterns solve problems in the user interface layers of an application that has a user interface.